# Who is this assassin?

Tags: game-identification, assassins-creed-series

I own a 2015 Assassin's Creed calendar with an image similar to the one shown below. I was wondering who the assassin on the far right is. As far as I remember, I don't recall seeing him in any of the games (or if he was, not depicted this way). Does anybody know where in the series he comes from? It seems to be the main characters from the original game through Black Flag (and the Freedom Cry DLC) so I'm not sure where he fits.

I've attached a zoomed picture of the calendar page itself as well. Should make it a little easier to see him.

[image: Image depicting many of the main characters of the Assassin's Creed series from the original Assassin's Creed to Black Flag]
[image: Zoomed picture of assassin in question]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is Nikolai Orelov.

[image: All characters with names]

He appears in:

- Assassin's Creed: The Fall
- Assassin's Creed: The Chain
- Assassin's Creed Chronicles: Russia

You can read more about him on the wiki page [here](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Nikolai_Orelov).

Comment: Sorry about the format. It's not the best as I'm on my phone.

Comment: fixed the formatting for you. I also added the games he's in from the Wiki :)

Comment: @Robotnik thanks. Looks much better now. Does using the app make it any easier than using a mobile browser?

Comment: a little bit, but Desktop is still probably the easiest to use, especially for writing questions and answers